# XML schema restriction pattern for not allowing empty strings

Tags: regex, xsd

In my XML schema I have element of type string that I don't want to be empty (if it contains white-spaces etc I also consider it empty)

I applied restrinction I found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/neerajag/archive/2005/08/12/450723.aspx

```
<xsd:restriction base = "xsd:string">
  <xs:minLength value="1" />
  <xs:pattern value=".*[^\s].*" />
</xsd:restriction>
```

What exactly does that pattern do and will do what I expect?

Answer (score 8):

doesn't this do exactly what you want?

```
 <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
  <xs:minLength value="1"/>
 </xs:restriction>
```

If the string contains only whitespace (line feeds, carriage returns, tabs, leading and trailing spaces), the processor will remove them so validation will fail; if there's anything else, validation will succeed.
(note though: internal sequences of two or more spaces will be removed - make sure you're ok with that)

Comment: It works but it works just because it uses:  <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> restriction. So no other magic is there.

Answer (score 7):

The pattern:

- zero or more characters `.*` (`.` matches any character).
- matches something not in the listed set of characters. `\s` is whitespace, so `[^\s]` is "match something that isn't a whitespace. The initial `^` in the match negates the normal match any one of these characters.
- zero or more characters.

Comment: It rejects text with carriage returns char. Why?

Comment: @jlp: "`.` matches any character" is the quick version. The full version includes a note that depending on the regex engine it might not match newlines *by default*. Try replacing `.*` with `[.\s]*` as `\s` matches includes both newline and carriage return.

Comment: Could you please write pattern that meets requirements from question?

Comment: @jlp: What requirement? The question is "what does this pattern mean?".

Comment: string that is not empty (only whitespaces and newlines means is empty too)

Comment: @jlp According to the XSD recommendation's definition of [`\s`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#dt-regex) it is equivalent to `[#x20\t\n\r]` – which includes both newline and carriage return. Therefore a string containing a single newline shouldn't match (since the character class has to match something). If such simple test cases are not correct then time to submit a short test case to the XSD engine's vendor.

Comment: According to the W3C documentation at [http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dt-regex](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dt-regex), section "G.4.2.5 Multi-character escapes" defines the `.` character sequence as the `[^\n\r]` character class.  So `.` matches any character except newline and carriage return.  I plan on using `[.\s]*\S[.\s]*`, now that I've read the suggestion from @Richard.  (Note that the documentation says that `\S` is defined as `[^\s]`.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if still useful but I found a better pattern than the first posted. Here it is:

```
<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="(\s*[^\s]\s*)+"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Using Eclipse, seems to work fine.

Comment: I just wrote 5 unit tests testing a) empty string b) single space c) d) multiple spaces containing a new line e) multiple spaces containing multiple new lines. It works for all those cases, so I would suggest that this is a good solution to anyone needing it! :) well done.

Comment: This is the only solution out of all the answers that works for my use case +1

Comment: This one works great, the difference compared to the thread posters example is that this uses \s* instead of .*, . does not match newline!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at subject of the post "pattern for not allowing empty strings" which is still unanswered. You can do that using  `<xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />` tag to disallow spaces

`whiteSpace` constraint set to `"collapse"`, it will do the following

1. removes all white space characters including line feeds, tabs,
   spaces, carriage returns
2. leading and trailing spaces are removed
3. multiple spaces are reduced to a single space

Reference: [W3C whiteSpace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace)

Comment: Your description of the 'collapse' value seems incorrect; especially number 1. The only part of number 1 that seems correct is the part that is duplicated in number 2. But considering your source (w3schools), I can see why you might be confused; W3Schools is a pretty low-quality source for many things. (see http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for pointing. I have also referred to W3C for reference W3C whiteSpace - http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace Point 2,3 seems to be perfectly correct. Although no mentioning of point 1 but it is also working Updated the Reference

Comment: Excellent update on the reference. I'm still a tiny bit not sure on #1 (#2, 3 are definitely correct, as you note). On #1, does it not convert those types of whitespace to spaces, rather than simply removing them? (and then, subsequently, collapses all spaces to a single space...)