# XSD Character Class Negate with group

Tags: xsd, negate, metacharacters

In my xsd I'm using negate to check for disallowed characters.  This is within a restriction pattern tag:

```
^[^ab]+$
```

This will allow any string unless it contains either a or b.

My requirement is that the string can contain anything but a or b or cd  (where c is allowed and d is allowed and dc is allowed but not cd).

From what I've read the Metacharacters inside square brackets does not include ( ) 's for grouping.

Is there another way to meet my requirement so that the xsd will validate that we are receiving valid data?

Thank You very much for your assistance.

Comment: C. M. Sperberg-McQueen addresses this tricky topic (disallowing a substring) very well in [**XML schema restriction pattern for not allowing specific string**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563199/xml-schema-restriction-pattern-for-not-allowing-specific-string).