# Make an xsd element mandatory

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml file that I am trying to validate against an xsd file. Works fine. I want to modify the xsd to make an element value mandatory. How do I do this so when I validate the xml file I want it to fail if the element `FirstName` is blank  (`<FirstName></FirstName>`)

**xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Patient>
   <FirstName>Patient First</FirstName>
   <LastName>Patient Last</LastName>
</Patient>
```

**xsd File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Patient">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014507/xml-schema-restriction-pattern-for-not-allowing-empty-strings) discussing how a schema restriction that disallows empty strings will help.

Comment: @Chandru Nagrani Did you solve this issue? if yes, how did you do it?

Answer (score 36):

### Mandatory

Attribute **minOccurs** Optional. Specifies the minimum number of times the any element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number >= 0. Default value is 1.
*(By default is mandatory)*

```
<!-- mandatory true-->
<xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" />
<!-- mandatory false-->
<xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

### Not Empty

```
<xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" >
  <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:minLength value="1"/>
     </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```