# How to validate if a xml element is empty using JAXB and a xsd schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I got an XML that I've to validate using an XSD schema, I already got the validation code if an element is missing using an **handleEvent**:

```
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) { }
```

```
JAXBContext readStructure=JAXBContext.newInstance(Cuentas.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller=readStructure.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
```

All I can handle with the **handleEvent** are errors,
Any ideas? (sorry if bad english)

Comment: Not sure if this would help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006103/how-to-enable-schema-validation-so-that-jaxb-rejects-empty-element)

Comment: So you can handle _errors_ with handleEvent. But you want to handle something else? Please can you explain (perhaps with an example) what you want to do.